# How to change default port(8080) of micronaut to something else?

Tags: micronaut

How to change default port `8080` in Micronaut to something else? I use Micronaut for my project, and I cannot find the configuration for changing the port number.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can specify a custom server port in `src/main/resources/application.yml` file, for instance:

```yaml
micronaut:
  server:
    port: 8081
```

Alternatively, you can set up an environment variable `MICRONAUT_SERVER_PORT`.

> For more information, check the official documentation page for [running on a specific port](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#runningSpecificPort).